# assembly read from file segmentation

Tags: file, assembly, io, segmentation-fault, armv8

```
    .data
pn:     .string "input.bin"
string: .string "%f\n"

buf_size = 8
alloc = -(16+buf_size)&-16
dealloc = -alloc
buf_s = 16

    .text
    .balign 4
    .global main
main:   stp x29,x30,[sp,alloc]!
    mov x29,sp

    mov w0,-100
    ldr x1,=pn
    mov w2,0
    mov w3,0
    mov x8,56
    svc 0
    cmp w0,0
    mov w19,w0
    mov w24,w19
    mov x20,0
    mov x21,8
    b.ge open_ok
open_ok:

    mov w0,w19
    add x1,x29,x21
    mov x2,8
    mov x8,63
    svc 0

    ldr d0,[x1]
    ldr x0,=string
    bl  printf
    add x21,x21,8

    cmp x20,199
    add x20,x20,1
    b.lt  open_ok

    mov w0,w24
    mov x8,57
    svc 0

    mov x1,x0
    ldr x0,=string
    bl  printf

    ldp x29,x30,[sp],dealloc
    ret
```

I'm trying to write a program that reads from a file "input.bin" and displays the contents of the file. It reads the file correctly and displays the data the way it is supposed to but right at the end it crashes due to a segmentation fault. Not sure whats going on. Input contains the numbers 0.5 to 100, incremented by 0.5 each time. It prints it out correctly and then crashes right at the end.

Comment: Which instruction is the fault happening on?

Comment: on the first "svc 0" after open_ok

Comment: I'm not an assembly programmer, but my guess is you're not checking for EOF correctly.

Comment: That's what i thought too, but I know exactly where the end of the file is. So i changed where the loop ends just to see and it still gets the same problem even if it ends well before the end of the file.

Comment: Is `x20` callee-saved register as per the calling convention? Have you used a debugger to see what's happening?